# How to fix this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to select the tickets that are pending each day of the past week.I have this query and get this error: **ORA-00935:** *group function is nested too deeply*

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day') AS WEEK_DAY, COUNT(ID) AS UPDATED_AT
  FROM freshdesk_api
 WHERE UPDATED_AT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw')
   AND UPDATED_AT < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7
   AND STATUS IN (3)
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day')
 ORDER BY MIN(UPDATED_AT)
```

Comment: I can not see any issue here. But can you please share what is the result if you remove `ORDER BY MIN(UPDATED_AT)` from your query?

Comment: Yea that seems to be the issue

Comment: The problem is calling the `COUNT()` the same name as a column in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want to order rows by the day of the week rather than by the count of rows per day.

However, your are aliasing the `COUNT()` with the same name as an date column, which causes ambiguity. Use a different alias - `UPDATED_AT` does not really make sense for a count anywayy:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day') AS WEEK_DAY, COUNT(*) AS CNT --> here
  FROM freshdesk_api
 WHERE UPDATED_AT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw')
   AND UPDATED_AT < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7
   AND STATUS = 3
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day')
 ORDER BY MIN(UPDATED_AT)
```

Or, if you really want that particular alias in the resultset, do prefix the column name in `MIN()` with the table name (or alias) to remove the ambiguity:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day') AS WEEK_DAY, COUNT(*) AS UPDATED_AT
  FROM freshdesk_api f                     --> table alias
 WHERE UPDATED_AT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw')
   AND UPDATED_AT < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7
   AND STATUS = 3
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day')
 ORDER BY MIN(f.UPDATED_AT)                --> prefixed column name
```

Notes:

- assuming that `id` is not nullable, `count(*)` is equivalent to `count(id)`, and more efficient
- `STATUS IN (3)` is simpler phrased `STATUS = 3`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the order by clause. I am not sure why you are using `MIN(UPDATED_AT)` but look into it to resolve your issue. If you are looking to sort by ascending order just use

```
ORDER BY UPDATED_AT ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an issue with `ORDER BY` as mentioned in the comment and in other answers.

Try to use the following technique to order the result from Monday to Friday.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day') AS WEEK_DAY, 
       COUNT(ID) AS UPDATED_AT, 
       MIN(UPDATED_AT) AS M_UPDATE_DATE -- ADDED THIS AND GAVE IT ALIAS
  FROM freshdesk_api
 WHERE UPDATED_AT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw')
   AND UPDATED_AT < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'iw') + 7
   AND STATUS IN (3)
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(UPDATED_AT, 'day')
 ORDER BY M_UPDATE_DATE; -- USED ALIAS NAME HERE
```